# Knockout.js not displaying child objects

Tags: knockout.js, asp.net-web-api

I having issues with getting knockout.js binding to display child objects that have the possibility of being null-able from ASP.NET Web Api.

I'm basically trying to create a searchable customer list (using a Jquery Datatable plugin) which the user will select a customer record to retrieve the full details of the customer (name, order history, customer notes, etc).  This customer detail will be displayed on the side of the datatable and some fields will be editable.  In my data model a customer can have zero, 1 or more notes and that's the object I'm having issues with.

**How to reproduce the issue**

On the UI, if the user selects a customer with a note, then knock binds and displays the notes properly.  If the user selects a customer wihhout a note then nothing is displayed (as expected), but when the user then selects another customer with a note, nothing is displayed (unexpected).

**The javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    //Party Model.
    var PartyModel = function (id) {
        var self = this;
        self.loaded = ko.observable(false);
        self.party = ko.observableArray([]);

        $.getJSON('api/party/GetParty?id=' + id, self.party).done(function () {
            self.loaded(true);
        });
    };

    //Customer List Datatable which is displayed on the left.
    custlisttable = $('#customerlist').dataTable({
        //"bServerSide": true,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bPaginate": false,
        "sAjaxSource": "api/PartyNameView/GetvPartyNamebyStoreID?storeid=1600", //"api/PartyNameView/GetvPartyName?id=2",
        "sAjaxDataProp": "",
        "sDom": 'R<"H"lfr>t<"F"iTp>',
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "aoColumns": [
                { "mDataProp": "DisplayName" },
                { "mDataProp": "PartyCategoryDesc"}],
        "oTableTools": {
            "sRowSelect": "single",
            "aButtons": [],
            "fnRowSelected": function (node) {
                aData = custlisttable.fnGetData(node); 
                $('#displayname').html(aData.DisplayName);
                id = aData.PartyID                      
                //get new party model using the PartyID (customerid).
                ko.applyBindings(new PartyModel(id));
                $("#accordion").show(750);
            }
        }
    });

    //Define the Contact Detail Accordian Section, but hide it until a record is selected.
    $("#accordion").accordion();
    $("#accordion").hide();
    $('.accordion .head').click(function () {
        $(this).next().toggle();
        return false;
    }).next().hide();
});
```

**The HTML**

```
<h2>Customers</h2>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span8">
        <!--Customer List using Datatable-->
        <table id="customerlist" class="display">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Company Name</th>
                    <th>Customer Type</th>             
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody> 
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div id="accordion">
                <h3><a href="#"><div id="displayname">[displayname]</div></a></h3>
                    <div>
                        <div data-bind="text: party().PartyID"></div>
                        <div data-bind="text: party().StoreID"></div>
                        <!--pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data)"></pre-->
                    </div>
                <h3><a href="#">People</a></h3>
                    <div>
                    <ul data-bind="foreach: party().People">
                        <li class="ui-widget" style="list-style-type: none; list-style-position: inside;">
                            <span data-bind="text: LastName"></span>, <span data-bind="text: FirstName"></span>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    </div> 
                <h3><a href="#">Notes</a></h3>
                    <div>
                    <ul data-bind="foreach: party().Notes">
                        <li class="ui-widget" style="list-style-type: none; list-style-position: inside;">
                            <span data-bind="text: NoteText"></span>
                        </li>
                        <li class="ui-widget" style="list-style-type: none; list-style-position: inside;">
                            <span data-bind="text: NoteID"></span>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Example JSON from Web API that contains a Note object.**

```
{"$id":"1","PartyID":1,"StoreID":"1600 ","ApprovedforAR":false,"PartyCategoryID":1,"PartyTypeID":1,"OrganizationID":1,"InvoiceHeaders":[],"Notes":[{"$id":"2","NoteID":2,"NoteText":"Test Note 1","PartyID":1,"Party":{"$ref":"1"},"PeopleNotes":[],"EntityKey":{"$id":"3","EntitySetName":"Notes","EntityContainerName":"appCateringFulfillmentEntities","EntityKeyValues":[{"Key":"NoteID","Type":"System.Int32","Value":"2"}]}},{"$id":"4","NoteID":3,"NoteText":"Deliveries only after 5","PartyID":1,"Party":{"$ref":"1"},"PeopleNotes":[],"EntityKey":{"$id":"5","EntitySetName":"Notes","EntityContainerName":"appCateringFulfillmentEntities","EntityKeyValues":[{"Key":"NoteID","Type":"System.Int32","Value":"3"}]}}],"PartyCategory":{"$id":"6","PartyCategoryID":1,"PartyCategoryDesc":"Category 1","Parties":[{"$ref":"1"}],"EntityKey":{"$id":"7","EntitySetName":"PartyCategories","EntityContainerName":"appCateringFulfillmentEntities","EntityKeyValues":[{"Key":"PartyCategoryID","Type":"System.Int32","Value":"1"}]}},"PartyType":{"$id":"8","PartyTypeID":1,"PartyTypeDesc":"Party Type 1","Parties":[{"$ref":"1"},{"$id":"9","PartyID":2,"StoreID":"1600 ","ApprovedforAR":false,"PartyCategoryID":2,"PartyTypeID":1,"InvoiceHeaders":[],"Notes":[],"PartyCategory":{"$id":"10","PartyCategoryID":2,"PartyCategoryDesc":"Category 2","Parties":[{"$ref":"9"}],"EntityKey":{"$id":"11","EntitySetName":"PartyCategories","EntityContainerName":"appCateringFulfillmentEntities","EntityKeyValues":[{"Key":"PartyCategoryID","Type":"System.Int32","Value":"2"}]}},"PartyType":{"$ref":"8"},"People":[{"$id":"12","PersonID":2,"FirstName":"Tom","LastName":"Harber","Title":"Accounting","PartyID":2,"Notes":[],"Party":{"$ref":"9"},"EntityKey":{"$id":"13","EntitySetName":"People","EntityContainerName":"appCateringFulfillmentEntities","EntityKeyValues":[{"Key":"PersonID","Type":"System.Int32","Value":"2"}]}}],"PostalAddresses":[],"ChannelAddresses":[],"EntityKey":{"$id":"14","EntitySetName":"Parties","EntityContainerName":"appCateringFulfillmentEntities","EntityKeyValues":[{"Key":"PartyID","Type":"System.Int32","Value":"2"}]}}],"EntityKey":{"$id":"15","EntitySetName":"PartyTypes","EntityContainerName":"appCateringFulfillmentEntities","EntityKeyValues":[{"Key":"PartyTypeID","Type":"System.Int32","Value":"1"}]}},"People":[{"$id":"16","PersonID":3,"FirstName":"Jared","LastName":"Kirkwood","Title":"Owner","PartyID":1,"Notes":[],"Party":{"$ref":"1"},"EntityKey":{"$id":"17","EntitySetName":"People","EntityContainerName":"appCateringFulfillmentEntities","EntityKeyValues":[{"Key":"PersonID","Type":"System.Int32","Value":"3"}]}}],"PostalAddresses":[],"Organization":{"$id":"18","OrganizationID":1,"OrganizationName":"Tony's Pizza Company","TaxExempt":false,"Parties":[{"$ref":"1"}],"EntityKey":{"$id":"19","EntitySetName":"Organizations","EntityContainerName":"appCateringFulfillmentEntities","EntityKeyValues":[{"Key":"OrganizationID","Type":"System.Int32","Value":"1"}]}},"ChannelAddresses":[],"EntityKey":{"$id":"20","EntitySetName":"Parties","EntityContainerName":"appCateringFulfillmentEntities","EntityKeyValues":[{"Key":"PartyID","Type":"System.Int32","Value":"1"}]}}
```

**Example JSON from Web API without a note.**

```
{"$id":"1","PartyID":2,"StoreID":"1600 ","ApprovedforAR":false,"PartyCategoryID":2,"PartyTypeID":1,"InvoiceHeaders":[],"Notes":[],"PartyCategory":{"$id":"2","PartyCategoryID":2,"PartyCategoryDesc":"Category 2","Parties":[{"$ref":"1"}],"EntityKey":{"$id":"3","EntitySetName":"PartyCategories","EntityContainerName":"appCateringFulfillmentEntities","EntityKeyValues":[{"Key":"PartyCategoryID","Type":"System.Int32","Value":"2"}]}},"PartyType":{"$id":"4","PartyTypeID":1,"PartyTypeDesc":"Party Type 1","Parties":[{"$ref":"1"},{"$id":"5","PartyID":1,"StoreID":"1600 ","ApprovedforAR":false,"PartyCategoryID":1,"PartyTypeID":1,"OrganizationID":1,"InvoiceHeaders":[],"Notes":[{"$id":"6","NoteID":2,"NoteText":"Hello Party World","PartyID":1,"Party":{"$ref":"5"},"PeopleNotes":[],"EntityKey":{"$id":"7","EntitySetName":"Notes","EntityContainerName":"appCateringFulfillmentEntities","EntityKeyValues":[{"Key":"NoteID","Type":"System.Int32","Value":"2"}]}},{"$id":"8","NoteID":3,"NoteText":"It's Tomato Fest","PartyID":1,"Party":{"$ref":"5"},"PeopleNotes":[],"EntityKey":{"$id":"9","EntitySetName":"Notes","EntityContainerName":"appCateringFulfillmentEntities","EntityKeyValues":[{"Key":"NoteID","Type":"System.Int32","Value":"3"}]}}],"PartyCategory":{"$id":"10","PartyCategoryID":1,"PartyCategoryDesc":"Category 1","Parties":[{"$ref":"5"}],"EntityKey":{"$id":"11","EntitySetName":"PartyCategories","EntityContainerName":"appCateringFulfillmentEntities","EntityKeyValues":[{"Key":"PartyCategoryID","Type":"System.Int32","Value":"1"}]}},"PartyType":{"$ref":"4"},"People":[{"$id":"12","PersonID":3,"FirstName":"Jared","LastName":"Kirkwood","Title":"Owner","PartyID":1,"Notes":[],"Party":{"$ref":"5"},"EntityKey":{"$id":"13","EntitySetName":"People","EntityContainerName":"appCateringFulfillmentEntities","EntityKeyValues":[{"Key":"PersonID","Type":"System.Int32","Value":"3"}]}}],"PostalAddresses":[],"Organization":{"$id":"14","OrganizationID":1,"OrganizationName":"Tony Tomato's Pizza Company","TaxExempt":false,"Parties":[{"$ref":"5"}],"EntityKey":{"$id":"15","EntitySetName":"Organizations","EntityContainerName":"appCateringFulfillmentEntities","EntityKeyValues":[{"Key":"OrganizationID","Type":"System.Int32","Value":"1"}]}},"ChannelAddresses":[],"EntityKey":{"$id":"16","EntitySetName":"Parties","EntityContainerName":"appCateringFulfillmentEntities","EntityKeyValues":[{"Key":"PartyID","Type":"System.Int32","Value":"1"}]}}],"EntityKey":{"$id":"17","EntitySetName":"PartyTypes","EntityContainerName":"appCateringFulfillmentEntities","EntityKeyValues":[{"Key":"PartyTypeID","Type":"System.Int32","Value":"1"}]}},"People":[{"$id":"18","PersonID":2,"FirstName":"Allen","LastName":"Harber","Title":"Helpdesk","PartyID":2,"Notes":[],"Party":{"$ref":"1"},"EntityKey":{"$id":"19","EntitySetName":"People","EntityContainerName":"appCateringFulfillmentEntities","EntityKeyValues":[{"Key":"PersonID","Type":"System.Int32","Value":"2"}]}}],"PostalAddresses":[],"ChannelAddresses":[],"EntityKey":{"$id":"20","EntitySetName":"Parties","EntityContainerName":"appCateringFulfillmentEntities","EntityKeyValues":[{"Key":"PartyID","Type":"System.Int32","Value":"2"}]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally was able to figure it out.  I was calling applyBindings each time the user selected datatable row.  According to some information I found, this is bad practice.

New View Model

```
viewModel = {
    Party: ko.observableArray([]),
    GetParty: function (id) {
        //Reset Party
        this.Party([]);
        //Retrieve the new data from the server.
        $.ajax({ url: "api/party/GetParty?id=" + id,
            accepts: "application/json",
            cache: false,
            statusCode: {
                200: function (data) {
                    viewModel.Party(data);
                }
                //TODO Handle other status codes
            }
        });
    }
};
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Then when the user clicks a row in the datatable just call GetParty in the fnRowSelected function.

```
viewModel.GetParty(id);
```